# Question About Proof of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

For each $n∈N$, let $f_n$ be defined for all $x∈R$ by $f_n(x)=\frac{x+cos^2(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ and let $f$ be defined for all $x∈R$ by $f(x)=0$.

$a)$ Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ on $R$ as follows:

For each $ε>0$ and  each $x∈R$ find explicitly a natural number $K(ε,x)$ such that for all $n≥K(ε,x)$ we will have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<ε$

$b)$ For any $a>0$, prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,a]$

Edit: My solution for $a)$ $f(x)=0$ Then $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$. For $0<x≤1$, $%\frac{1}{x}≥1$. Hence: $|f_n(x)|=\frac{1+cos^2n}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}}}≤\frac{1+cos^2n}{\sqrt{n}}$, $n→∞$ equals to $0.$ Is it enough for prove this?
Still no idea for $b)$.

Comment: Well, a) gives you *instructions* on how to get started.

Comment: Definition review: pointwise convergence: for all $\epsilon\gt0$, there is a number $N\gt0$ such that as long as $n\gt N$, $\lvert f_n(x_0)-F(x_0)\rvert\lt\epsilon$; uniform convergence: for all $\epsilon\gt0$, there is a number $N\gt0$ such that as long as $n\gt N$, for all $x\in[a,b]$, $\lvert f_n(x)-F(x)\rvert\lt\epsilon$. (and that please don't expect us to do your homework)

Comment: So $f(x)=0$ Then $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$. For $0<x≤1$, $%\frac{1}{x}≥1$. Hence: $|f_n(x)|=\frac{1+cos^2n}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}}}≤\frac{1+cos^2n}{\sqrt{n}}$ $n→∞$ equals to $0.$ Is it enough for prove this?

Comment: @SaintRS Consider adding that to your question; people usually rush to the "close" dialogue before viewing the comments

Comment: Your method for (a) doesn't match the instructions. Also, $f_n(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for showing. My bad $f_n(0)≠f(x)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) 
$\epsilon>0,x\in R:$ by definition:
$\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|=|{\frac{x+\cos^{2}(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}-0}|=|{\frac{x+\cos^{2}(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}-0}|=|{\frac{x+\cos^{2}(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}}|\leq|{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{n}}}|$
let's choose: $n=\left(x+1\right)^{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}$
we get: $|\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{n}}|=|\frac{x+1}{\left(x+1\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}}|=\epsilon$, as needed.

b)

$sup_{x\in\left[0,a\right]}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=sup_{x\in\left[0,a\right]}|\frac{x+\cos^{2}(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|\leq sup_{x\in\left[0,a\right]}|\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{n}}|=|\dfrac{a+1}{\sqrt{n}}|\to0$

Comment: Thanks but why did you select $n=(x+1)^2\frac{1}{ϵ^2}$ ?

Comment: so that it will end up being exactly epsilon (the square is there because of the root)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Note that by the Archimedian property, for any real number $x$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $(1+|x|)<N \epsilon.$

Therefore, for any $x$, and for any $n \geq N$.  we have  $|\frac{x+cos^2(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}-0| \leq \frac{|x|+1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{|x|+1}{n} \leq \frac{|x|+1}{N} < \epsilon.$

This proves that $f_{n}$ converges to $0$ pointwise.

For the second part, note that $|x|+1 \leq 1+a.$ So, you can find $\epsilon$ independent of $x$, that we means  $f_{n}$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $[0, a].$